# signOut being passed as props from one component to App.js, but on click on logout icon doesn't allow to logout from system

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-oauth

In my react hooks `signOut` is being passed as props from `DashboardNav.js` component to App.js. On click on logout icon in App.js is not actually logging out from the system. I am actually using gapi-scirpt for performing the logout operation, could someone please advise me how can i achieve this ?

CodeSandBox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-ioana-pz5jyz?file=/src/dashboardNav.js:0-1199

// App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DashboardNavbar from "./dashboardNav";
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";

export default function App() {
  const [isMobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);

  const { signOut } = () => {
    alert("hello");
    const auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    if (auth2 != null) {
      auth2.signOut().then(
        auth2.disconnect().then(console.log("LOGOUT SUCCESSFUL")),
        localStorage.removeItem("loginEmail"),
        localStorage.removeItem("userImage"),
        //history.push("/"),
        console.log("Logged out successfully !")
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DashboardNavbar
        logout={signOut}
        onMobileNavOpen={() => setMobileNavOpen(true)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

// dashboardNav.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  AppBar,
  Badge,
  Box,
  Hidden,
  IconButton,
  Toolbar
} from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import NotificationsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/NotificationsOutlined";
import InputIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Input";

const DashboardNavbar = ({ onMobileNavOpen, signOut, ...rest }) => {
  const [notifications] = useState([]);

  return (
    <AppBar elevation={0} {...rest} style={{ background: "#1976D2" }}>
      <Toolbar>
        <RouterLink to="/">
          <img alt="Logo" src="images/simpro.PNG" width="80px" />
        </RouterLink>
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
        <Hidden mdDown>
          <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={signOut}>
            <InputIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden lgUp>
          <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={onMobileNavOpen}>
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Hidden>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

DashboardNavbar.propTypes = {
  onMobileNavOpen: PropTypes.func
};

export default DashboardNavbar;
```