# I want to change admin value to true but it is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [admin, setadmin] = useState(false);
  const toggleIsLoading = () => {
    admin?setadmin(false):setadmin(true)
  };
 
  return (
    <div className="signup">
      <div className="register_head">
        <h1>REGISTER YOURSELF</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <div>
          <label for="options">I'm: </label>
          <select className="options">
            <option id="emp" value={admin}>
              Employee
            </option>
            <option onClick={toggleIsLoading}>Admin</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

I want to change `admin` value to true but it is not working.

I tied several things but state is not changing.

Comment: did you check our answers?

Comment: why "toggleIsLoading" is connected to isAdmin? that doesn't make any sense! second, you can simplify this function by setting: `setadmin(!admin)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are trying to fire `onClick` eventListener on `<option></option>` tag, but neither `onclick` nor `onselect` eventListener are supported on the `<option></option>` tag.

In order to fire the `toggleIsLoading` function you need to fire a function on `onChange()` eventListener from the `<select></select>` tag.

JS

```js
  const [admin, setadmin] = useState(false);
  const toggleIsLoading = () => {
    console.log("TRIGGERED");
    admin ? setadmin(false) : setadmin(true);
  };
```

HTML

```html
 <div className="signup"></div>
      <div className="register_head">
        <h1>REGISTER YOURSELF</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="options">I'm: </label>
          <select className="options" onChange={toggleIsLoading}>
            <option id="emp" value={admin}>
              Employee
            </option>
            <option>Admin</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: If you got spare time, could you please advise this one here>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74203831/signout-being-passed-as-props-from-one-component-to-app-js-but-on-click-on-logo

Answer (score 0):

Use `onChange` inside your `select` tag and handle the value accordingly.
Here is a simple example

```
  const toggleIsLoading = (event) => {
    setadmin(event.target.options.selectedIndex === 1)
    // or  e.g.--> setadmin(!admin)
  };


  <select onChange={toggleIsLoading} className="options">
    <option id="emp" value={admin}>
      Employee
    </option>
    <option>Admin</option>
  </select>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-shannon-k256p3)